# Parsing a VARCHAR row by a delimiter and updating the table rows as such in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing, split, substring

I am having a very difficult time with this. I have a table that looks like the following.

```
    movieID | Genre 
----------------------------
    1         Action | Comedy
    2         Drama
    3         Action | Horror | Thriller
    4         Comedy | Drama
    5         Action | Suspense | Comedy
```

And I need to convert it to look like the following...

```
    movieID | Genre
-----------------------------
    1         Action
    1         Comedy
    2         Drama
    3         Action
    3         Horror
    3         Thriller
    4         Comedy
    4         Drama
```

I've been looking around everyone online, all I can seem to find examples of are queries that will output the data looking like this. However, what I want to know  is whether or not there is a way to actually update the table data to look like this? Not just create a query that looks like the desired output without changing the actual information stored within the table.

Is it possible? From what I can tell it does not seem like it is and perhaps I am beating a dead horse trying to find a solution to this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `MERGE` statement with any of the [many ways to split delimited strings](https://web.archive.org/web/20170914140540/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7d7c/18)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table movies ( movieID, Genre ) AS 
  SELECT 1, 'Action | Comedy' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Drama' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Action | Horror | Thriller' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Comedy | Drama' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Action | Suspense | Comedy' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
MERGE INTO movies dst
USING (
  WITH movie_genres ( rid, movieID, lvl, maxlvl, genre, all_genres ) AS (
    SELECT ROWID rid,
           movieID,
           1,
           REGEXP_COUNT( genre, '(.+?)(\s*\|\s*|$)' ),
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( genre, '(.+?)(\s*\|\s*|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ),
           genre
    FROM   movies
  UNION ALL
    SELECT rid,
           movieID,
           lvl + 1,
           maxlvl,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( all_genres, '(.+?)(\s*\|\s*|$)', 1, lvl + 1, NULL, 1 ),
           all_genres
    FROM   movie_genres
    WHERE  lvl < maxlvl
  )
  SELECT rid, movieID, lvl, genre FROM movie_genres
) src
ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID AND src.lvl = 1 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET genre = src.genre
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( movieID, genre ) VALUES ( src.movieID, src.genre )
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY movieId
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7d7c/18/1)**:

```
| MOVIEID |    GENRE |
|---------|----------|
|       1 |   Comedy |
|       1 |   Action |
|       2 |    Drama |
|       3 |   Action |
|       3 |   Horror |
|       3 | Thriller |
|       4 |   Comedy |
|       4 |    Drama |
|       5 | Suspense |
|       5 |   Comedy |
|       5 |   Action |
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly! I have a follow up question if you don’t mind. Would it be possible to perform this operation as a procedure?

Comment: @KevinGombos yes, it is possible to wrap this in a procedure.